# How to make an optional Parameterized.Parameter in JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit

I have to work with a JUnit test that has autowired parameters from a collection with the annotation `@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")`, there is already a lot of tests in that collection. I want to add a parameter, but as most programmers are, I'm a very lazy person, so I would like to introduce an optional parameter, is that possible?

```
@Parameterized.Parameter()
importantParameter;

@Parameterized.Parameter(1)
evenMoreImportantParameter;

@Parameterized.Parameter(2)
businessHandshakeBusinessYes;

@Parameterized.Parameter(3)
meBeingLazyOptionalParameter;

@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new Object[]{ "wow", "very", "impressive"});
    params.add(new Object[]{ "wow", "much", "beautiful"});

    // Where I want to be lazy
    params.add(new Object[]{ "this", "is", "sooooo", "better"});
        
    return params;
}
```

In the case shown previously, only the last test will be successful, the first 2 tests will generate the following error message

```
java.lang.Exception: Wrong number of parameters and @Parameter fields. @Parameter fields counted: 4, available parameters: 3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the source code of `Parameterized.class` and `BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.class` shows that it's not possible to specify an optional parameter.

Personally, I would keep all the parameters the same size, but you can always create your unit runner copying the `Parameterized.class` and padding the array to the max size with `null`.

Here's an example of a `Parameterized` runner that does the padding (a copy of the original one in JUnit but with the private method `allParameters` adapted):

```
public class Parameterized extends Suite {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public static @interface Parameters {

        String name() default "{index}";

        // The max number of parameters
        int size();
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Inherited
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    public @interface UseParametersRunnerFactory {

        Class<? extends ParametersRunnerFactory> value() default BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory.class;
    }

    private static final ParametersRunnerFactory DEFAULT_FACTORY = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory();

    private static final List<Runner> NO_RUNNERS = Collections.<Runner>emptyList();

    private final List<Runner> runners;
    private final int  size;


    public Parameterized(Class<?> klass) throws Throwable {
        super(klass, NO_RUNNERS);
        ParametersRunnerFactory runnerFactory = getParametersRunnerFactory( klass);
        Parameters parameters = getParametersMethod().getAnnotation( Parameters.class);
        size = parameters.size();
        runners = Collections.unmodifiableList(createRunnersForParameters( allParameters(), parameters.name(), runnerFactory));

    }

    private ParametersRunnerFactory getParametersRunnerFactory(Class<?> klass)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        UseParametersRunnerFactory annotation = klass
                .getAnnotation(UseParametersRunnerFactory.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            return DEFAULT_FACTORY;
        } else {
            Class<? extends ParametersRunnerFactory> factoryClass = annotation.value();
            return factoryClass.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Runner> getChildren() {
        return runners;
    }

    private TestWithParameters createTestWithNotNormalizedParameters(String pattern, int index, Object parametersOrSingleParameter) {
        Object[] parameters= (parametersOrSingleParameter instanceof Object[])
                ? (Object[]) parametersOrSingleParameter
                : new Object[] { parametersOrSingleParameter };
        return createTestWithParameters(getTestClass(), pattern, index, parameters);
    }

    private Iterable<Object> allParameters() throws Throwable {
        Object parameters = getParametersMethod().invokeExplosively(null);

        if (parameters instanceof Iterable) {
            return pad((Iterable<Object>) parameters);
        } else if (parameters instanceof Object[]) {
            return pad(Arrays.asList((Object[]) parameters));
        } else {
            throw parametersMethodReturnedWrongType();
        }
    }

    private Iterable<Object> pad(Iterable<Object> parameters) {
        List<Object> padded = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Object parameter : parameters ) {
            Object[] paddedParams = new Object[size];
            Object[] current = (Object[]) parameter;
            System.arraycopy( current, 0, paddedParams, 0, current.length );
            padded.add( paddedParams );
        }
        return padded;
    }

    private FrameworkMethod getParametersMethod() throws Exception {
        List<FrameworkMethod> methods = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(
                Parameters.class);
        for (FrameworkMethod each : methods) {
            if (each.isStatic() && each.isPublic()) {
                return each;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("No public static parameters method on class " + getTestClass().getName());
    }

    private List<Runner> createRunnersForParameters(
            Iterable<Object> allParameters, String namePattern,
            ParametersRunnerFactory runnerFactory)
            throws InitializationError,
            Exception {
        try {
            List<TestWithParameters> tests = createTestsForParameters(
                    allParameters, namePattern);
            List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<Runner>();
            for (TestWithParameters test : tests) {
                runners.add(runnerFactory
                        .createRunnerForTestWithParameters(test));
            }
            return runners;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw parametersMethodReturnedWrongType();
        }
    }

    private List<TestWithParameters> createTestsForParameters(
            Iterable<Object> allParameters, String namePattern)
            throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        List<TestWithParameters> children = new ArrayList<TestWithParameters>();
        for (Object parametersOfSingleTest : allParameters) {
            children.add(createTestWithNotNormalizedParameters(namePattern,
                    i++, parametersOfSingleTest));
        }
        return children;
    }

    private Exception parametersMethodReturnedWrongType() throws Exception {
        String className = getTestClass().getName();
        String methodName = getParametersMethod().getName();
        String message = MessageFormat.format( "{0}.{1}() must return an Iterable of arrays.", className, methodName);
        return new Exception(message);
    }

    private static TestWithParameters createTestWithParameters(
            TestClass testClass, String pattern, int index, Object[] parameters) {
        String finalPattern = pattern.replaceAll("\\{index\\}", Integer.toString(index));
        String name = MessageFormat.format(finalPattern, parameters);
        return new TestWithParameters("[" + name + "]", testClass, Arrays.asList(parameters));
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I guess that I'll just append a null parameter everywhere. That seems like basic functionality, but yeah I looked through the source code too and could not find anything me neither...whatever I guess

Comment: I've added the code for a custom Parameterized unit runner if you are interested. It works the same way of the original one but you can specify the size of the parameters.